# Highly variable execution times in Cython functions

Tags: python, performance, cython

I have a performance measurement issue while executing a migration to Cython from C-compiled functions (through scipy.weave) called from a Python engine.

The new cython functions profiled end-to-end with `cProfile` (if not necessary I won't deep down in cython profiling) record cumulative measurement times highly variable.

Eg. the cumulate time of a cython function executed 9 times per 5 repetitions (after a warm-up of 5 executions - not took in consideration by the profiling function) is taking:

- in a first round 215,627339 seconds
- in a second round 235,336131 seconds

Each execution calls the functions many times with different, but fixed parameters.
Maybe this variability could depends on CPU loads of the test machine (a cloud-hosted dedicated one), but I wonder if such a variability (almost 10%) could depend someway by cython or lack of optimization (I already use hints on division, bounds check, wrap-around, ...).

Any idea on how to take reliable metrics?

Comment: Are you measuring actual execution time consumed, or merely the elapsed (wall-clock) time?  If it's the elapsed time, you have circumstances beyond your control -- such as server load -- that make your figures of questionable accuracy.

Comment: It's cProfile measured time on mere function, but I don't know if it is possible to avoid sensibility to server load on any method. What I am seeking is a way to do it

Answer (score 1):

*First* of all, you need to ensure that your measurement device is capable of measuring what you need: specifically, only the system resources *you* consume.  UNIX's `utime` is one such command, although even that one still includes swap time.  Check the documentation of your profiler: it *should* have capabilities to measure *only* the CPU time consumed by the function.  If so, then your figures are due to something else.

Once you've controlled the external variations, you need to examine the internal.  You've said nothing about the complexion of your function.  Some (many?) functions have available short-cuts for data-driven trivialities, such as multiplication by 0 or 1.  Some are dependent on an overt or covert iteration that varies with the data.  You need to analyze the input data with respect to the algorithm.

One tool you can use is a line-oriented profiler to detail where the variations originate; seeing which lines take the extra time should help determine where the "noise" comes from.

Comment: I am going to check if there is some non-deterministic behaviour but since functions code depends on function-inputs only (that are fixed) and does not rely on any state I'd expect that the path undertaken in each round is exactly the same. That is true unless bugs, so I am going to check again

Comment: Ah ... Now I see what you meant by that phrase in your question: each run operates on the same sequence of call arguments.  That eliminates one large segment of my worries.  Thanks also for clarifying the state: initial state could still affect the operation, but you're checking that.  I'd still do a line-oriented profile; this would help you identify random system interruptions, as well.

Comment: Also, when you do this multiple times, is there any primacy effect?  Is the first run always the faster one?  A degradation in performance might suggest a lengthening list or memory allocation ... ?

Comment: I think the last one is an interesting point. I have to measure single executions since Cython part could have some memory issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a performance expert but from my understanding the thing you should be measuring would be the average time it take per execution not the cumulative time? Other than that is your function doing any like reading from disk and/or making network requests?

Comment: The functions don't do any I/O (db, network, ...), it's math calculus on large timeseries. I've avoided average measurements, since they didn't seem significant. Anyhow the number of calls is a constant on every round, so I don't expect different results, but it's worth trying